# How Yocto embeds systemd in end project?

Tags: systemd, embedded, systemd-unit

How can I customize systemd source code? When I do bitbake, systemd appears in my end project, but I cannot find any source files of it in my local directories. I want to track down unit files lifecycle, log_debug(...) and log_info(...)s are not showing up (some of the messages appear, but gives not enough info for me) in journalctl in my embedded project. Does Yocto pulls systemd source files, compiles and then deletes them, if so how can I prevent deletion, customize code and then recompile?

Comment: Like with all other system components: A recipe defines where to download the sources, which branch or tag to use and how to compile it. If you want to modify it, write a patch and create a `bbappend` recipe in your own yocto layer to apply the patch. Btw, the source files are not deleted; you should be able to find them somewhere in `tmp/work`.

Comment: I searched several times, but no systemd source files there. I found in one of the systemd directories run.do_rm_work file where it says in comments: "# If the recipe name is in the RM_WORK_EXCLUDE, skip the recipe." I did it by uncommenting and adding a name "systemd" in my local.conf. It did not work either.@Philippos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides adding recipe name to the `RM_WORK_EXCLUDE += "systemd"` in `local.conf`, one should clean shared state using one of the cleaning options provided by **Yocto**, for example `$ bitbake -c cleansstate recipe` before bitbaking again, otherwise, with an unflushed shared state cache it will start from the current state, not from the beginning. More information on cleaning state and much more is on the [yoctoproject website](https://docs.yoctoproject.org/ref-manual/tasks.html#do-clean).